# Apache POI add a Series name into LineChart

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

I am creating a LineChart using Apache POI in Excel document. As far as I've managed to achieve is in the below image:

[image]

I wrote the code using examples from Apache's svn, so my current approach looks like this:

```
Drawing drawing = question.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 14, 18);

Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
ChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

LineChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();

ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
bottomAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

List<ReportQuestionModel> questionModels = groupModel.getQuestionModels();
for (ReportQuestionModel questionModel : questionModels) {

    List<ReportOptionModel> optionModels = questionModel.getOptionModels();
    for (ReportOptionModel optionModel : optionModels) {
        rowNum++;

        XSSFRow optionRow = question.createRow(rowNum);

        XSSFCell optionsCell = optionRow.createCell(0);
        optionsCell.setCellValue(optionModel.getAnswerText());

        long count = optionModel.getCount();
        totalResponses += count;

        XSSFCell optionsCountCell = optionRow.createCell(1);
        optionsCountCell.setCellValue(count);

        XSSFCell optionsPercentageCell = optionRow.createCell(2);
        optionsPercentageCell.setCellValue(optionModel.getPercentage());
    }
}

ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(question, new CellRangeAddress(8, 8, 0, 1));
for (int i = 9; i <= rowNum; i ++) {
    ChartDataSource<Number> ys = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(question, new CellRangeAddress(i, i, 0, 1));
    data.addSerie(xs, ys);
}
chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
```

What I can't find is how to get default `"Series 1", "Series 2", ..., "Series n"` names to be taken from as my values from the columns, in this case from: "Answer options". And there doesn't seem to be any methods in the current API how to specify names of the series.

Can anybody assist me with this, please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was pretty straight forward, just instead of using:

```
data.addSeries(xs, ys);
```

I had to be using:

```
LineChartSeries chartSeries = data.addSeries(xs, ys);
chartSeries.setTitle("My Title");
```

Didn't look at the API that using `data.addSeries(xs, ys);` returns a single `LineChartSeries` object onto which I can set a title.

Answer (score 2):

From Apache POI version 3.16 onwards, use setTitleText("Title Name") instead.
Also the correct class name is LineChartSeries not LineChartSerie. 
So, the above solution would look like:

```
LineChartSeries chartSeries = data.addSeries(xs,ys);
chartSeries.setTitleText("My Title");
```

for Apache POI 3.16 onwards.