# Add line marker to line series/chart (Apache POI XSSF or Excel VBA)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, vba

I have studied [Apache POI Example on how to create a line chart](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/LineChart.java).

It output a single line chart like the chart in [Apache POI add a Series name into LineChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855842/apache-poi-add-a-series-name-into-linechart).

[image]

How can I add the line marker to the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am using Apache POI 3.10.  So far, Apache POI XSSF can't add line marker! So, I use excel vba to do it.**

What I do is I have create a xlsm template with VBA macro to add line marker when user open the xlsm file. Also, we can't add the VBA macro by POI as mentioned in [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html),

```
Macros can not be created. The are currently no plans to support macros. However, 
reading and re-writing files containing macros will safely preserve the macros.
```

Therefore we have to create a template and use it as an POI input.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("template.xlsm"));
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

Here is my VBA macro:

```
Sub auto_open()

Dim myChart As ChartObject
    For Each myChart In Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects
        For Each Series In myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
            Series.MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleSquare
        Next
    Next myChart
End Sub
```

By using this workaround, we can add more style to the simple output line chart of POI.