# Error when creating new XSSFWorkbook .xlsx file?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to run the BarChart example provided by Apache Poi to create an XSSFWorkbook with the example class.

I have poi-ooxml version 4.1.0 in my maven build and am using Eclipse as my IDE.

I've read some posts but most of them have to do with the order of closing the workbook and closing the outputstream but that is not my issue. It fails on the actual workbook.write() command. I cannot seem to figure out why this is the case?

I also read some things about missing jar files, but I'm using the maven dependencies so I don't see how this could happen.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
   /* ====================================================================
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
==================================================================== */

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.PresetColor;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFShapeProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.XDDFSolidFillProperties;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisCrosses;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.AxisPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.BarDirection;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.ChartTypes;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.LegendPosition;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFBarChartData;
    import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFCategoryAxis;
    import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartData;
    import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChartLegend;
    import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFDataSourcesFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFNumericalDataSource;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFValueAxis;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/**
 * Line chart example.
 */
public class BarChart {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("barchart");
            final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 3;
            final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 10;

            // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
                row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
                    cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
                    cell.setCellValue(colIndex * (rowIndex + 1.0));
                }
            }

            XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);

            XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
            chart.setTitleText("x = 2x and x = 3x");
            chart.setTitleOverlay(false);
            XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
            legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

            // Use a category axis for the bottom axis.
            XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            bottomAxis.setTitle("x"); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010765
            XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
            leftAxis.setTitle("f(x)");
            leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

            XDDFDataSource<Double> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, 2, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));

            XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.BAR, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
            XDDFChartData.Series series1 = data.addSeries(xs, ys1);
            series1.setTitle("2x", null); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855842
            XDDFChartData.Series series2 = data.addSeries(xs, ys2);
            series2.setTitle("3x", null);
            chart.plot(data);

            // in order to transform a bar chart into a column chart, you just need to change the bar direction
            XDDFBarChartData bar = (XDDFBarChartData) data;
            bar.setBarDirection(BarDirection.COL);
            // looking for "Stacked Bar Chart"? uncomment the following line
            // bar.setBarGrouping(BarGrouping.STACKED);

            solidFillSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.CHARTREUSE);
            solidFillSeries(data, 1, PresetColor.TURQUOISE);

            // Write the output to a file
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-bar-chart.xlsx")) {
                wb.write(fileOut);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void solidFillSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
        XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
        XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
        XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
        }
        properties.setFillProperties(fill);
        series.setShapeProperties(properties);
    }
}
```

However, when trying to run the code I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: gnu.xml.dom.DomDocument.getXmlStandalone()Z
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.setDocumentInfo(DOM2TO.java:377)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:693)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:351)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.StreamHelper.saveXmlInStream(StreamHelper.java:84)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.saveImpl(ZipContentTypeManager.java:69)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.save(ContentTypeManager.java:452)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:524)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1488)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:242)
    at com.tapestry.tcot.BarChart.main(BarChart.java:108)
    Suppressed: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: gnu.xml.dom.DomDocument.getXmlStandalone()Z
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.setDocumentInfo(DOM2TO.java:377)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:131)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:693)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:351)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.StreamHelper.saveXmlInStream(StreamHelper.java:84)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.saveImpl(ZipContentTypeManager.java:69)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.save(ContentTypeManager.java:452)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:524)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1488)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.close(OPCPackage.java:454)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.close(POIXMLDocument.java:204)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.close(XSSFWorkbook.java:586)
        at com.tapestry.tcot.BarChart.main(BarChart.java:110)
```

Comment: The reason is a discrepancy of dependency resolving between compile time and run time. While run time a method is abstract that was not abstract at compile time. Wild guess: From an old `JFreeChart` version you have `gnujaxp.jar` in class path while run time? Do removing it and try again.

Comment: Yep. That was the issue. Updated JFreeChart to 1.5.0 in my pom file and it worked. Thank you very much!